# Registry get directory owner programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, registry

I want to read programmatically the owner of a directory (and its subdirectories) of the windows registry using C#.

For example, assume my registry contains the directory `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft` which is owned by the user `SYSTEM`. A code example (leaving out the recursion over sub-directories of `dir`) how I intend to use it would be:

```
string dir = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft";
string owner = ReadRegOwner(dir); // owner is "SYSTEM"
```

However, I am not sure how to implement `ReadRegOwner` in C#. I have already found the [RegistrySecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity?view=netframework-4.8) class, but I am not sure how to use it to get the owner of a registry directory. It has the `GetOwner` member function, but that function requires an argument of type `Type` and I am not sure what to pass there.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: It seems to be an _identity_ reference, `typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)` should do (untested).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ok, now I need to know how to create an identity reference to my registry directory I guess?

Comment: No, just use the code in the comment.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Unfortunatly, the code returns null... I also don't see how it links to a concrete directory? Somewhere, I would have to define the directory.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ok, I got it to work: on the key, GetAccessControl must be called. On its return value, we can use GetOwner. Thanks.

Comment: post it as answer, I'm sure someone else will need it!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Good point, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, an implementation could look like:

```
string ReadRegOwner(string dir)
{
    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(dir, false);
    RegistrySecurity rs = key.GetAccessControl();
    IdentityReference owner = rs.GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

    return owner.ToString();
}
```

Example:

```
string dir = @"Software\Microsoft";
string owner = ReadRegOwner(dir); // Looks in HKEY_CURRENT_USER
```

Of course, `CurrentUser` could be also replaced if a different base key than `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is desired.